# After iOS 5.0.1 upgrade, Test iAds unavailable on iPad 2

Tags: ios5, iad, ipad-2

Both versions of my first App "Puffer's Train challenge" are currently sitting in the Apple queue "In Review". Saturday night I upgraded my iPhone 4 from 5.0 to 5.0.1 and also installed 5.0.1 on a new iPad 2.

Built & installed Lite versions of my app with iAds onto both devices. 5.0.1 initially caused both to crash. I was able to resolve that quickly (bad order of framework calls on my part) However! I spent the REST of Sunday trying to chase down any reason that test iAds are being served up to my iPhone (using wireless connection only to compare apples-to-apples), but the same code and the same calls fail with the error message "No inventory available" on my connected "wireless only" iPad 2.

App is built using xcode 4.2 for iphoneos, not universal, so I verified that the iAd framework call: `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` is returning 320x50 as it should. I "think" this rules out any problem that would be caused by different sized iAd requests.

Has anyone else experienced this same issue with Apple's test Ads using an iPad 2 device upgraded to 5.0.1? If so, I'd love to know that so I can stop (or at least slow down) pulling my hair out!

ps. Google's AdMob ads with which I replace iAds when not available, work Just Fine!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with iAds. Doesn't work on device or in simulator for iPad 5.0 or 5.0.1, but does for 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing a Build & Install you're not using the Live (read: App Store) version of your app. This is why you're seeing Test Ads instead of actual Live ads.

Any time I've ever install an app to a device with Xcode I'm greeted with Test Ads from Apple. I believe this is because Apple intelligently looks at your app (either the version numbers or the provisioning file baked into the app) and knows that it's a developer build.

Now, if you're seeing Test Ads from the version of your app you've downloaded from the App Store then that's an entirely different problem. I've seen this as well but it doesn't sound like your problem.